# Foursquare - How to get more than 100 venues using foursquare API?

Tags: javascript, php, foursquare

In Foursquare API Explorer window, We have used the endpoints 'venues/search?ll=39.8647,-86.2604&intent=browse&radius=20000&limit=200' to get the venues more than 100 but it should return only 50 venues.

```
Can anyone kindly give the solution that which endpoints be able to get more than 200 venues using foursquare API?
```

Thanks,
Bargavi

Answer (score 1):

You should try the ["venues/explore"](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) endpoint. It has an offset parameter to page through results.

Although, it might not return the results you expect since it browses recommended venues for the current user. But you can sort the venues by distance afterward with a few lines of code.