# How do I get more than 50 venues using the Foursquare API in search mode?

Tags: python, foursquare

I'm implementing a simple Python project for study purposes and I want to retrieve 200 different burger locations using the Foursquare API within a radius.

I've tried to make four consecutive calls with "search", but the results from each call are overlapping. I've also checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629184/foursquare-how-to-get-more-than-100-venues-using-foursquare-api), but the offset is limited to 50 (so I can only get 100 results by making two calls).

I want to make sure that none of the venues are repeated without having to check the responses of each call and I don't want to traverse the results one by one.

Is there a simple way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `limit` Parameter.
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/search

Comment: I know there is this parameter, but the docs also state that it is limited by 50. Even if you ask for a value higher than 50, it only returns 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way around the `limit` of 50 on the `venues/search` endpoint, unfortunately, at least nothing documented.

As the other answer pointed out you can use the `venues/explore` endpoint, along with `offset` to get each next set of 50 (`limit`). Depending on the parameters used (`query`, `categoryId`, `section`, etc), and if you hit this endpoint as an unauthenticated user (so you don't get customized results), you *may* be able to replicate the same set of results as you would from `venues/search`.

Comment: Confirming that 50 is the max for the `limit` parameter.